# AFNetworking http client not sending JSON parameters

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlrequest, afnetworking

I created a subclass of `AFHTTPClient` and am trying to send some JSON parameters to a server.

However the server is responding with a Expected content type

```
{(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got application/xml
```

According to [AFNetworking FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ)

> If you're using AFHTTPClient, set the parameterEncoding property to AFJSONParameterEncoding. Any method on that HTTP client with a parameters argument will now encode the passed object into a JSON string and set the HTTP body and Content-Type header appropriately.

I've done that here but the server appears not to recognize the content-headers. Does anyone know of a potential solution?

Here is the method:

```
- (void)getCompanyDataWithString:(NSString*)companySearchQuery 
      finish:(LBMarkitAPIRequestCompletionBlock)finishBlock
{
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
        companySearchQuery forKey:@"input"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *searchQueryRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET"
        path:kMarkitCompanyURL parameters:params];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *searchRequestOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation 
        JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:searchQueryRequest 
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@",json);
            NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

            NSError *anError = [[NSError alloc] init];
            if ([json objectForKey:@"Message"]) 
            {
                NSString *message = [json objectForKey:@"Message"];
                anError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:message
                                                     code:100 
                                                 userInfo:nil];
            }

            // Need some error handling code here
            for (id item in json) 
            {
                NSString *aName = [item objectForKey:@"Name"];
                NSString *aSymbol = [item objectForKey:@"Symbol"];
                NSString *anExchange = [item objectForKey:@"Exchange"];

                LBCompany *aCompany = [[LBCompany alloc] initWithName:aName 
                    Symbol:aSymbol Exchange:anExchange];
                [results addObject:aCompany];
            }
            // Need to run the passed in block after JSON 
            // Request Operation succeeds

            finishBlock(results,anError);
          }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, 
            NSError *error, id JSON)
        {
            NSLog(@"request failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@",JSON);
        }];

    [searchRequestOperation start];
    NSLog(@"JSON operation started");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with URL formatting. I didn't notice an API implementation detail that made sending Query Parameters necessary and also specifying JSON output in the URI.

There were no issues with regard to AFNetworking.

Comment: Hi, I think I have the same problem but still haven't figured out how to solve it. Can you please tell me more about what you were doing wrong with the API and how you fixed it.

Comment: You can check out my solution here: http://github.com/andrewjl/Aperio/blob/master/Aperio/LBHTTPClient.m